# Improving the tag system (categories)

Tags: discussion, tagging, user-interface

was thinking there are so many tags around (around 27 pages)

How can we improve the tag system,

some suggestions:

- can we not create categories that group tags together, so that instead of looking for 30 different tags you can just look for one or two categories. (maybe in some hierarchical structure so categories can contain categories as well)
- some kind of classification. (problem some subjects can belong to more than one classification)

Also I noticed that in the taglist synonyms are not marked as such, can that be added?

Comment: This seems related to the previous discussions [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6573/sub-tags-and-over-tags) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/should-questions-on-matrices-and-matrix-equations-be-also-tagged-as-linear/9626#9626).

Comment: Similar feature request at meta.SO: [A proposal for tag hierarchy on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so/)

Comment: I posted a similar suggestion in [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10245/12952).  Long story short, I think it's a good idea so long as using parent/sister tags isn't mandatory.